# Laravel Mix and VUE, VUE not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, webpack

So I have been getting this NPM error and I cannot figure out why just VUE cannot be resolved. I am using Laravel 5.6. This is a new install of Laravel with some light web pack configuration. I have resolved path in webpackConfig to VUE and I believe it is failing at the extract step in the webpack.mix.js

Vue is installed in node_modules/vue

error is generated using npm run dev and npm run prod

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
"@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
"axios": "^0.18",
"babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"cross-env": "^5.1",
"jquery": "^3.2",
"laravel-mix": "^2.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.5",
"pace": "github:HubSpot/pace#v1.0.2",
"perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
"popper.js": "^1.14.4",
"simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
"sweetalert2": "^7.0.7",
"vue": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "imagemin": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix Asset Management
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
| for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
| file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
|
*/
mix.setPublicPath('public');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Webpack Config
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/axios/dist'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/lodash'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/sweetalert2/dist'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/popper.js/dist')
    ]
  }
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Vendor Extraction
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
mix.extract([
  'vue',
  'jquery',
  'axios',
  'sweetalert2',
  'lodash',
  'js/bootstrap',
  'popper.js'
]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoload Dependancies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
mix.autoload({
  jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery']
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix App Resources
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| app.js | Application Javascript file
| app.scss | Applciation SCSS file
*/
mix
.js(['resources/js/app.js'], 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix In Production
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
if (mix.inProduction() || process.env.npm_lifecycle_event !== 'hot') {
mix.version();
}
```

NPM Error

```
ERROR in multi vue jquery axios sweetalert2 lodash js/bootstrap popper.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/Path/To/Project/Project-Folder'
 @ multi vue jquery axios sweetalert2 lodash js/bootstrap popper.js
```

app.js

```
 /**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: Did you install vue?  What command did you run to generate this error?

Comment: Vue is installed, I used npm run dev, npm run prod also throws the error.

Comment: Have you tried `path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist'),`?

Comment: @Devon I just did, I still get the same error.

Comment: in `resources/assets/js/app.js` you probably have this line `require('bootstrap')` or `import bootstap from './bootstrap'`  comment it and retry

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I do have that. Even with it commented out I get the same error. I added my app.js file

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days,
Surprisingly: Removing `require('./bootstrap')` line, Works & now Vue Devtools is able to detect vue js.

Anyone might have any idea why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack.mix file you have the following line:
`path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue'),`

Just make sure that this is correct, It maybe that you need to target a dist folder or similar e.g.

`path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist'),`